# sp_help - table is referenced by an 'empty string' schema bound view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to systematically determine the differences in schema between a local database and a remote database administered by someone else.  I've had the remote administrator run a script that executed sp_help and sp_helptext on a variety of objects.

There is one difference I don't know how to account for.  On my local system sp_help on one table produces a line of message output **No views with schema binding reference table 'dbo.tbl'**.

On the remote system, the output was '**Table is referenced by views**' followed by a **blank line**.  The query was run with output as text so this indicates on the remote machine a one row result set was produced with an empty string (or NULL?) value.

How can that happen?  If I create a schema bound view locally I get the 'Table is referenced by views' output followed by the name of the view plainly displayed.  What scenario on the remote machine could be producing this result set without any view name recorded?

Comment: Maybe someone accidentally deleted part of the name from the view! (Sounds funny but I've had someone rename a table accidentally before...). Probably not, but that's an interesting scenario you have.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question requires knowledge of the internal workings of sp_help. You are welcome to descend into the depths of procedures that are called by sp_help. If you do, you will see that this procedure uses sysdepends - which is both not "dependable" and obsolete. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysdepends-transact-sql . The short answer is that something has been altered/renamed in a way that is not captured in sysdepends.